# How to remove object from array in power shell?

Tags: json, windows, powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to remove the complete object from the array not a member of the object.I am not able to find the way to remove the object there are so many solutions available to remove the item.
    Can someone please suggest a way remove the complete object.

```
JSON Data: JSON data stored in the file.

{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "Caption",
      "firstname": "Caption",
      "lastname": "test",
      "email": "test",
      "requester": "test",
      "password": "test",
      "incNumber": "test"
    }
  ]
}

Code : I have written the following code to read the object from the array and store into variables to do the task.Once the task is completed I want to remove the object from the array.

$file = Get-Content '\path\to\file' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$file.data | % {if($_.id -eq 'Caption'){
        $1 = $_.id
        Write-Host $1
        ###Here I want to remove the whole object related to the id
    }}
```

Comment: `$file.data = $file.data | ? id -ne 'Caption'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer in the comments is what you are looking for: `file.data = $file.data | ? id -ne 'Caption'`.

To give a little explanation to this, it uses `?` which is actually an alias (alternative name) for the `Where-Object` cmdlet, which is what you use when you want to filter a collection based on some criteria (very similar to the `WHERE` statement in SQL if you are familiar).

The above answer is a short version, you might alternatively see this:

```
$file = Get-Content '\path\to\file' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$Result = $file.data | Where-Object {$_.id -ne 'Caption'}
```

Which is passing a ScriptBlock `{ }` to the Where-Object cmdlet and using `$_` to represent each item in the pipeline, then using `-ne` as the not equals comparison operator to see if the `ID` property of that object does not match the string `Caption`. If that is evaluated as true, then it allows the item to pass through the pipeline, which in the above example means it ends up in the `$Result` variable. If the statement evaluates as false, then it discards that item in the collection and moves on to the next.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.I am able to read the object and use the data in next steps.What I want is when it is used and process completed I want to remove this object from the list.Can you please tell me a way to remove it from the list.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? What do you do with the filtered list afterwards? You could use the where cmdlet to create a filtered list in one variable, while processing them the way you currently are. Does that help?

Comment: It is temp location where I am trying to hold the data for some time and use it when I get next request.After the request is served I want to clear the array list because it is no longer needed so no point of storing it.Please let me know if there is anything wrong with this process.

Comment: Then just set it to $null at the end?